# Power Apps (canvas) with Dynamic Form Questions

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I work on a team that has historically produced many types of VBA-based tools for internal customers in our business unit, primarily in Excel. We are gradually transitioning these tools to Office 365 and the Power Platform (Power Apps, Power Automate, Power BI).

One of these tools is a "modernized" data entry form (currently a VBA UserForm in Excel) for a compliance assessment input/tracker. There are a series of questions where the user is required to provide a Y/N response, with a mandatory "comment" when the "N" response is selected.

As it's currently built in VBA UserForms, we have tables set up for the assessment questions that are associated with a "version" number, so we can release updates to the assessment without impacting historical data (which we must retain for a period of time). The VBA UserForm "dynamically" creates edit controls to collect the responses and then saves these to our SQL database in a "responses table" (separate from the form questions themselves).

How can a canvas Power App be designed for this existing data structure, where the assessment questions must be "dynamically generated", without needing to re-engineer the database already in use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the technique shown in the article below with apps created for my clients. Please have a look, best of luck!

https://clarissagillin2.blogspot.com/2020/09/introducing-infinityform.html

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the link! So my impression from this is to use a gallery for the question inputs, and it worked out really well. There is occasionally some issue where the controls are "populating" with values when they shouldn't, but that's a separate issue and it's not consistent (if I "refresh" the screen they go back to the blank defaults).